# How to use django oram to implement oracle wm_concat query

Tags: django, oracle, django-models

In oracle, I can use wm_concat to implement row-to-column conversion, as follows:

`SELECT * FROM STU_TEST`

| name | project |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Machine Learning |
| Alice | Data Science |
| Bob | Web Development |
| Bob | Mobile Development |
| Carol | Data Science |
| Carol | Cloud Computing |
| David | Artificial Intelligence |

`SELECT NAME,wm_concat(PROJECT) FROM STU_TEST GROUP BY NAME`

| name | wm_concat(PROJECT) |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | Machine Learning,Data Science |
| Bob | Web Development,Mobile Development |
| Carol | Data Science,Cloud Computing |
| David | Artificial Intelligence |

I want to implement this query using django orm, I tried the following, without success.

它返回了错误:`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models.aggregates import Count
from myapp.models import StuTest
from django.db.models import Func

class GroupConcat(Func):
    function = 'LISTAGG'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s, \',\') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %(expressions)s)'

results = StuTest.objects.values('name').annotate(project_concat=GroupConcat('project')).order_by('name')

for result in results:
    print(result['name'], result['project_concat'])
```

How to implement this query? (In the actual environment, group by may not only include the name field, but also other fields)

Comment: `wm_concat` is undocumented and was removed in Oracle 12. Don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, wm_concat is not necessary, I just want to achieve a similar query effect

Comment: Looks like you need to inherit from [aggregate function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/aggregates.py), not from more generic `Func` that is less strict. Please try `from django.db.models import Aggregate ... class GroupConcat(Aggregate)`